# rstudio-server "unauthorized user" error on google vm

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a Google VM with Rstudio server installed. Everything was working fine and I was able to get in with my username and password. I haven't used this VM for a couple months and now I tried again. I am getting the Rstudio login page when typing `<server-ip-address>:8787`, but when I enter my username and password I get the "unauthorized user" error. I'm not sure what changed.

The only similar post I found was this [Cannot log in to AWS RStudio Server and Workbench, instead see 'Error: Unauthorized user.'](https://community.rstudio.com/t/cannot-log-in-to-aws-rstudio-server-and-workbench-instead-see-error-unauthorized-user/126381), which turned out to be an AWS problem.

I can SSH into the server with my user. It is not a password problem (since then you get a different error). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved it:

First, I checked the rstudio-server log file:

```
sudo cat /var/log/rstudio/rstudio-server/rserver.log
```

where I found the following message:

```
WARNING User user_name could not be authenticated because they do not belong to one of the required groups (analysts,admins,rstudio-users); LOGGED FROM: bool rstudio::server::auth::validateUser(const string&, const string&, unsigned int, bool) src/cpp/server/auth/ServerValidateUser.cpp:125
```

When trying to add my user to one of the groups
`analysts,admins,rstudio-users`, I found that none of them exist in my system. So first I added a new group called `rstudio-users`:

```
sudo groupadd rstudio-users
```

Then I added my user to the group:

```
sudo usermod -a -G rstudio-users user_name
```

And then I restarted rstudio-server:

```
sudo systemctl restart rstudio-server
```

And that solved it.

Comment: Man, I spent hours on this issue. I solved. Thanks a lot